# Changing commands permission levels

Tags: minecraft

I've created a Minecraft Server to play with my friends, but we wanted to use the last snapshot, so we had to download the official version from minecraft.net. For this reason, we can't add plugins to our server. I'd like to allow a list of commands (like teleport or / function), denying the others (like / give or / gamemode), but how could I do that?

I had an idea; usually there are different OP permission level

- Lvl 1: you can't use commands
- Lvl 2: you can use some commands
- Lvl 3: you can kick and ban
- lvl 4: you can stop the server

Could I create a new OP level? Like a lvl 5 where you can just use the command / tp or / function?
I've searched the declaration file for hours, without finding it. Does it really exists or is it located in the library of the game rather than the server?

Or could I do something with the server.properties file? I saw there are two different keys:

- function-permission-level
- op-permission-level

Are this two things linked to each other? I've tried to set both equal to 1, then I /op myself, but still I can't use the / function command.

Thanks for the help, Jacopo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do that using default spigot or what ever. OP is actually contains some minecraft permissions (minecraft.command.gamemode for example /gamemode 0/1 etc.) that came to you from /op  command. You need to download permission plugin.(2+ variants in the internet, you can use PermissionsEx) It will allow you to create some other groups aside OP(like users, vip, premium, admin and others)